# DD4T | DD4T.ContentModel.Logging.ILogWrapper not found

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, dd4t, dd4t-2

For MVC5,

I have installed the package: DD4T.LogWrappers.Log4NET using below command successfully:

```
install-package DD4T.LogWrappers.Log4NET -Version 2.0.0-alpha5
```

Surprisingly, the DD4T website started throwing below error. When using MVC4, installing the same package is fine.

Below is the Exception logged while calling `builder.UseDD4T()`:

**Could not load type 'DD4T.ContentModel.Logging.ILogWrapper' from assembly 'DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4450e3c7f68bf872'**

[image: below is the <code>Global.asax.cs</code> file co]

I also verified the DLL and there is NO DD4T.ContentModel.Logging folder/namespace present as seen below for **MVC5**:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong DLL for DD4T logging.

Try using `DD4T.Logging.Log4Net.dll` version `2.2.0`
 
URL: http://www.nuget.org/packages/DD4T.Logging.Log4Net/2.2.0

You seem right that , with MVC5 onwards, The namespace `DD4T.ContentModel.Logging` is moved to dll `DD4T.Core.Contracts`.

And,  BTW, how and where do you got the `DD4T.LogWrapper.Log4NET.dll` ? It is unlisted by authors on Nuget.

Comment: using DD4T.Logging.Log4Net.dll worked like a charm for me. I guess www.nuget.org is the correct website for packages. I mistakenly downloaded the logwrapper dll from STAGING website: http://staging.nuget.org/packages/DD4T.LogWrappers.Log4NET/

Comment: What purpose is the staging website of nuget is for ? Also, if it is staging why is it visible to public ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you are installing `D4T.LogWrappers.Log4NET -Version 2.0.0-alpha5` version, but you are getting error message related to 2.2.1.0 version

```
DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts, Version=2.2.1.0
```

So, I suspect that it is a version mismatch issue and you can resolve it by updating the right version of your dependencies in your package.config file.